# Nothing after DELETE gets executed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
    MATCH (u:User)
        WHERE u.id = $userId
    MERGE (p:Palette {name: $name})
        ON CREATE 
            SET p.name = $name
            SET p.id = apoc.create.uuid()
            MERGE (u)-[cr:CREATED]->(p)
    MERGE (u)-[sa:SAVED]->(p)
    WITH p MATCH (p)-[in:INCLUDES]->() 
        DELETE in
    WITH u MATCH (p:Palette)
        WHERE (u)-[:SAVED]-() AND p.name = $name
    FOREACH (color IN $colors |
        MERGE (c:Color {hex: color.hex})
        ON CREATE 
            SET c.hex = color.hex
        MERGE (p)-[inc:INCLUDES]->(c)
```

Everything works as expected up to `DELETE in` and then nothing else happens. I get the following error:

> Neo4jError: Invalid input '': expected
> ")"
> "CALL"
> "CREATE"
> "DELETE"
> "DETACH"
> "FOREACH"
> "LOAD"
> "MATCH"
> "MERGE"
> "ON"
> "OPTIONAL"
> "REMOVE"
> "RETURN"
> "SET"
> "UNWIND"
> "USE"
> "WITH"

How can I continue this query after the `DELETE statement`? If I separate this into 2 queries (the first one ending at `DELETE in`), then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `p` before the `DELETE` is the same as the `p` after it. Id this is the case, use `WITH` to keep the items you already searched for. So you can try:

```
    MATCH (u:User)
        WHERE u.id = $userId
    MERGE (p:Palette {name: $name})
        ON CREATE 
            SET p.name = $name
            SET p.id = apoc.create.uuid()
            MERGE (u)-[cr:CREATED]->(p)
    MERGE (u)-[sa:SAVED]->(p)
    WITH p, u MATCH (p)-[inc:INCLUDES]->() 
    WITH p, u, inc
        DELETE inc
    WITH p
    FOREACH (color IN $colors |
        MERGE (c:Color {hex: color.hex})
        ON CREATE 
            SET c.hex = color.hex
        MERGE (p)-[inc:INCLUDES]->(c)
```

I tried:

```
MATCH (p:Palette)
WHERE p.name = "First test palette"
MATCH (p)-[inc:INCLUDES]->(c:Color)
WITH p, inc
DELETE inc
WITH p
MATCH (u)-[:SAVED]-(p)
RETURN u, p
```

On this data sample:

```
MERGE (e:User {name: "user"})
MERGE (a:Palette {name: "First test palette"})
MERGE (b:Color {hex: "#123123"})
MERGE (c:Color {hex: "#ffffff"})
MERGE (d:Color {hex: "#000000"})

MERGE (a)-[:INCLUDES]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[:INCLUDES]-(c) 
MERGE (a)-[:INCLUDES]-(d) 
MERGE (e)-[:SAVED]-(a)
```

And it worked as expected.

Comment: I have a neo4j question that seems similar to this one but I cannot resolve it. Would you be willing to assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720677/neo4j-delete-a-nodes-existing-relationships-and-create-new-relationship