# Neo4j delete a nodes existing relationships and create new relationship

Tags: neo4j

I want a query that will delete all of the existing relationships from a particular node and then create a new relationship. This is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (m:Movie  {
  _id: 'test/55de0539eb1e14f26a04'
})
MATCH (existingNode:Person  {
  _id: 'test/41126fc03289a05d8621'
})
MATCH (existingNode)-[existingRelationships]->()
DELETE existingRelationships
WITH existingNode, m
CREATE (existingNode)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN existingNode;
```

And this works as I would like when the existingNode has at least one existing relationship. However if the existingNode has zero existingRelationships when I run this query the new relationship is not created. It is as if nothing after the DELETE statement is run if there was nothing to delete.

How can I chain on the CREATE even when there was nothing to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `OPTIONAL` and also `distinct`.

**Explanation**: According to neo4j concept of [cardinality](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-cypher-cardinality/), if we have several matches, we will get a row for each one of them. Therefore, if several nodes are connected to `existingNode` we will get several rows as a result, one for each connected node. The `existingNode` will repeat in all of them, causing next steps regarding to it, to be duplicated. In our case the new connection step will be preformed multiple times.

Without the `OPTIONAL` if there are zero nodes connected to it, we will get zero rows, which is the other problem.

So when using the `OPTIONAL`, after the `DELETE` step we have multiple `existingNode`, as the number of `existingRelationships`, but at least one, thanks to the `OPTIONAL`. We still need to use `distinct` to avoid creating multiple relationships to `m`:

```
MATCH (existingNode:Person  {
  key: 'A'
}) 
WITH existingNode
OPTIONAL MATCH (existingNode)-[existingRelationships]->()
DELETE existingRelationships
WITH distinct existingNode as existingNode
MATCH (m:Movie  {key: 'B'})
WITH existingNode, m
CREATE (existingNode)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN existingNode, m
```

It works well for the sample data with relationships to delete:

```
MERGE (a:Person{key: 'A'})  
MERGE (b:Movie{key: 'B'})
MERGE (c:Node{key: 'C'})
MERGE (d:Node{key: 'D'})
MERGE (e:Node{key: 'E'})

MERGE (a)-[:POINTS]-(c)
MERGE (a)-[:POINTS]-(d) 
MERGE (a)-[:POINTS]-(e)
```

And another one without relationships to delete:

```
MERGE (a:Person{key: 'A'})  
MERGE (b:Movie{key: 'B'})
```

For both cases it returns:

```
╒══════════════╤═══════════╕
│"existingNode"│"m"        │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╡
│{"key":"A"}   │{"key":"B"}│
└──────────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say "After the DELETE step we have multiple existingNode, as the number of existingRelationships, but at least one, thanks to the OPTIONAL"? 

Why would we have multiple existingNode?

Comment: Updated the Explanation, per your request. Basically, it is a result of the cardinality concept

Comment: Try using my sample data with your code, and you should get three relationships between `existingNode`  and `m`, for the three original connected nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use an OPTIONAL MATCH before the DELETE e.g.

```
MATCH (m:Movie  {
  _id: 'test/55de0539eb1e14f26a04'
})
MATCH (existingNode:Person  {
  _id: 'test/41126fc03289a05d8621'
})
OPTIONAL MATCH (existingNode)-[existingRelationships]->()
DELETE existingRelationships
WITH existingNode, m
CREATE (existingNode)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN existingNode;
```

I believe the behavior of Neo4j is to break out of the query if any MATCH statement fails to return any items. The OPTIONAL MATCH allows the query to continue even when no items match:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

Comment: Please check my answer, I think it also solves multiple relationships between `existingNode` and `m`